# Displaying equation with a line break and all subsequent lines indented

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

In answering [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294521/getting-text-to-appear-on-the-same-line/), I recommended some changes to the OP and provided the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{aligned}
    |f_{n}&(x)g_{n}(x) - f_{n}(x)g(x) + f_{n}(x)g(x) - f(x)g(x)| \\
    &\leq |f_{n}(x)g_{n}(x) - f_{n}(x)g(x)| + |f_{n}(x)g(x) -
    f(x)g(x)| \\
    &= |f_{n}(x)||g_{n}(x) - g(x)| + |g(x)||f_{n}(x) - f(x)| \\
    &\leq M_{1}\epsilon + M_{2}\epsilon \\
    &= \epsilon(M_1+M_2) \longrightarrow 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty
  \end{aligned}      
\]

\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

What I really wanted to do, though, is follow the advice of 3.3.5c of [Mathematics Into Type](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/author-info/documentation/howto/mit-2.pdf), which recommends breaking at conjunctions and aligning with two-em quad from the left.

That I think is possibly open to interpretation, but what I would like is to have:

```
|f_{n}&(x)g_{n}(x) - f_{n}(x)g(x) + f_{n}(x)g(x) - f(x)g(x)|
```

On one line, a line break and all subsequent lines indented by a two-em quad and aligned. In other words, I want what I have, but with a precisely two-em quad indentation:

[image]

Unfortunately, the above is the closest I've been able to come. I tried:

```
\begin{align*}
  |f_{n}(x)g_{n}(x) - f_{n}(x)g(x) + f_{n}(x)g(x) - f(x)g(x)| \\
  \qquad &\leq |f_{n}(x)g_{n}(x) - f_{n}(x)g(x)| + |f_{n}(x)g(x) -
  f(x)g(x)| \\
  &= |f_{n}(x)||g_{n}(x) - g(x)| + |g(x)||f_{n}(x) - f(x)| \\
  &\leq M_{1}\epsilon + M_{2}\epsilon \\
  &= \epsilon(M_1+M_2) \longrightarrow 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty
\end{align*}
```

But that doesn't work at all:

[image]

Comment: Do you want the (in)equality signs below `(x)`?

Comment: @Sigur Ah, sorry if I haven't explained myself properly. What I want is the (in)equality signs aligned with each other and indented exactly two-em quad from the start of the equation. Any equation, in fact. My hack - the best I could do - puts the signs more or less below `(x)` but what I'm aiming for is precisely two-em quad from the leftmost end of the equation. This was just an example. It looks alright this time, but in the next inequality, I may not be able to find a good spot to align and it may not be in the same place. I'm after a way to make the indentation two-em quad every time.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250489/multiple-alignment-in-math-mode-a-math-equivalent-to-multicolumn.

Comment: He he, that exact picture (with the two lines) was exactly why `\MoveEqLeft` was added to `mathtools` as described below. I got a version of the image from **Mathematics into type** published by the AMS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) provides the `\MoveEqLeft` function which achieves exactly what you want.  By default, it indents subsequent lines by 2em and it can be further customized with `\MoveEqLeft[<number>]` which will indent subsequent line by `<number>` ems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \MoveEqLeft |f_{n}(x)g_{n}(x) - f_{n}(x)g(x) + f_{n}(x)g(x) - f(x)g(x)| \\
  &\leq |f_{n}(x)g_{n}(x) - f_{n}(x)g(x)| + |f_{n}(x)g(x) - f(x)g(x)| \\
  &= |f_{n}(x)||g_{n}(x) - g(x)| + |g(x)||f_{n}(x) - f(x)| \\
  &\leq M_{1}\epsilon + M_{2}\epsilon \\
  &= \epsilon(M_1+M_2) \longrightarrow 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty
\end{align}      
\begin{align}
  \MoveEqLeft[4] |f_{n}(x)g_{n}(x) - f_{n}(x)g(x) + f_{n}(x)g(x) - f(x)g(x)| \\
  &\leq |f_{n}(x)g_{n}(x) - f_{n}(x)g(x)| + |f_{n}(x)g(x) - f(x)g(x)| \\
  &= |f_{n}(x)||g_{n}(x) - g(x)| + |g(x)||f_{n}(x) - f(x)| \\
  &\leq M_{1}\epsilon + M_{2}\epsilon \\
  &= \epsilon(M_1+M_2) \longrightarrow 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty
\end{align}      
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: The `mathtools` package loads `amsmath` automatically -- thus, no need to load `amsmath` explicitly.

Comment: @Mico I'm aware that `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, but I still prefer to load `amsmath` because a lot of IDEs read the `usepackage` declarations in order to load the appropriate commands and environments.

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you want?

```
\begin{align*}
  &|f_{n}(x)g_{n}(x) - f_{n}(x)g(x) + f_{n}(x)g(x) - f(x)g(x)| \\
  &\qquad \leq |f_{n}(x)g_{n}(x) - f_{n}(x)g(x)| + |f_{n}(x)g(x) - f(x)g(x)| \\
  &\qquad = |f_{n}(x)||g_{n}(x) - g(x)| + |g(x)||f_{n}(x) - f(x)| \\
  &\qquad \leq M_{1}\epsilon + M_{2}\epsilon \\
  &\qquad = \epsilon(M_1+M_2) \longrightarrow 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! That's exactly the right output, thank you :) Obviously this approach has the downside of an inelegant input, but that's certainly what I wanted to produce :)

Comment: @Au101, see the elegant answer by JP-Ellis.

Comment: Yes indeed, he will most likely get the tick, but I wanted to thank you for bearing with me and let you know you'd definitely understood my question :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `mathenv` of the `mdwtools` collection,
you can use the enhanced `{eqnarray}` environment.
It takes optional column specifiers:

- `r`, `c`, `l` for right-justified, centered, and left-justified math;
- `L` for left-justified math that is considered to have width 2em;
- and more (read the documentation) so you can completely emulate
  the functionality of `amsmath` environments like `{align}` and others.

Here, you'd use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{mathenv}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*}[Ll]
|f_{n}(x)g_{n}(x) - f_{n}(x)g(x) + f_{n}(x)g(x) - f(x)g(x)| \\
&\leq |f_{n}(x)g_{n}(x) - f_{n}(x)g(x)| + |f_{n}(x)g(x) -
f(x)g(x)| \\
&= |f_{n}(x)||g_{n}(x) - g(x)| + |g(x)||f_{n}(x) - f(x)| \\
&\leq M_{1}\epsilon + M_{2}\epsilon \\
&= \epsilon(M_1+M_2) \longrightarrow 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image: mathenv eqnarray L demo]